# How do I write a function in rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console

I am trying to write a function in the rails console, and in the example, this is how the function should look in terminal.

```
>> def string_message(str = '')
>>   return "It's an empty string!" if str.empty?
>>   return "The string is nonempty."
>> end
```

How do they create a new line while still making the console realize it is all of the lines create a function. Would it be accurate to write it as:

```
>> def string_message(str = '') \n\t return "It's an empty string!" if str.empty? \n\t blah blah \n\t
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IRB, the ruby console in which `rails console` relies supports this out of the box.

Just type your function declaration, press the enter key, then input the body line by line, and finally type `end`.

You'll see text like this:

```
2.4.1 :001 > def say_hi(person)
2.4.1 :002?>   puts "Hi #{person}"
2.4.1 :003?>   end
 => :say_hi 
2.4.1 :004 > say_hi("Nina")
Hi Nina
 => nil 
2.4.1 :005 >
```

Notice how the `?` indicates that IRB is waiting for more input before evaluating the expression.

Comment: For some reason, there is no ?. It does show the name of the function once the final end is placed. Thank you